# Trouble with ADT in ubuntu

Tags: android, adt, ubuntu-13.10

Recently I had switched my OS from winodows to ubuntu 13.10, For android application development I had installed ADT, My problem is I am not able to import an application to the eclipse, At certain time it is possible for me to import the project but in most of the time its not. Also there is jar file missing as well as manifest missing problem facing while we integrate a third party library, Can anybody can solve my problems..?

Comment: What errors do you get? What is the name of the jar file ?

Comment: Actually I got error while integrating actionbarSherlock, jar misplaced error

Comment: In ABS project or the other project ?

Comment: Which jar does it complain about?